# Unable to add anything in the body - Intel XDK App Designer

Tags: html, intel-xdk

I am using Intel XDK for Mobile UI Design and I have inserted a header which contains pictures and text. However i am unable to add anything in the body. I try to drag different components into the body but nothing happens. Seems that i can only add anything into the header. Here is my code: The content inside the`<h4>` does not appear on the screen. (this is in `<!-- /upage-content -->`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media_button_bar/css/media_button_bar.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/design.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_main.less.css" class="main-less">
        <title>Your New Application</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        <style type="text/css">
            /* Prevent copy paste for all elements except text fields */
            *  { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }
            input, textarea  { -webkit-user-select:text; }
        </style>
        <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /* Intel native bridge is available */
            var onDeviceReady=function(){
            //hide splash screen
            intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
            };
            document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
        </script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="marginal/marginal-position.min.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="modal/js/modal.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="js/index_user_scripts.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body class="body">

        <!-- content goes here-->

        <div class="uwrap">
            <div class="upage" id="mainpage">
                <div class="upage-outer">
                    <div class="uib-header header-bg container-group inner-element uib_w_1 uib-header-fixed" data-uib="layout/header" data-ver="0" id="header">
                        <img class="header_image" src="images/hku_logo.png">
                        <div class="header_text">
                            HKU Mobile
                        </div>

                        <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right">

                            <a class="uib-graphic-button default-graphic-sizing hover-graphic-button default-graphic-button widget uib_w_2 d-margins" data-uib="media/graphic_button" data-ver="0" id="login_lock">
                                <img src="images/Login_lock.png">

                                <span class="uib-caption"></span>
                            </a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /upage-content -->

                    <h4> sdsajidojasid</h4>

                </div>
                <!-- /upage-outer -->


                <!-- popup Portal Login box -->
                <div class="modal outer-element uib_w_4 Portal_popup" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/modal" data-ver="0" id="Portal_popup" data-backdrop="false" data-keyboard="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Login to HKU Portal</h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="col uib_col_1 single-col" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                                    <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

                                        <div class="table-thing widget uib_w_5 popup_text1" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/input" data-ver="0">
                                            <label class="narrow-control label-top-left">HKU Portal ID</label>
                                            <input class="wide-control form-control input-sm" type="text" placeholder="Enter your HKU Portal UID" id="portal_id">
                                        </div>
                                        <br>
                                        <div class="table-thing widget uib_w_6 d-margins" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/input" data-ver="0">
                                            <label class="narrow-control label-top-left">HKU Portal PIN</label>
                                            <input class="wide-control form-control input-sm" type="password" placeholder="Enter your HKU Portal PIN" id="portal_pin">
                                        </div>
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn widget uib_w_7 d-margins btn-primary" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="0"><i class="glyphicon button-icon-left" data-position="left"></i>Log in</button>
                                        <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /upage -->
        </div>
        <!-- /uwrap -->
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was missing from my code:

`<div class="upage-content" id="mainsub">` when the header `<div>` closes